# Необработанное исключение System.Net.WebException во время запроса WebClient

Tags: c#, вконтакте

```
var uploadServer = api.Photo.GetWallUploadServer(id);
var awda = new WebClient();
MessageBox.Show(uploadServer.UploadUrl);
var responseImg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(awda.UploadFile(uploadServer.UploadUrl,
    "POST", "https://vk.me/images/safari_152.png"));

var photos = api.Photo.SaveWallPhoto(responseImg, null, id);
var result = api.Wall.Post(id, false, true, text, photos, null);
```